# Get root application for a web site using Powershell WebAdministration module

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5, azure-web-roles

I'm attempting to configure serviceAutoStartEnabled and serviceAutoStartProvider properties of a web application at the root of a web site deployed in Azure.  If I understand the auto start process these properties can be set for specific web applications under a single web site.

I am executing a powershell script during web role start (after elevated privileges have been obtained in a startup task) to perform the web administration tasks as shown here:

```
write-host "Begin RoleStart.ps1"

import-module WebAdministration

Add-WindowsFeature NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45,NET-WCF-TCP-Activation45,NET-WCF-Pipe-Activation45

$listenerService = Get-WmiObject win32_service -filter "name='NetPipeActivator'"
$listenerService.ChangeStartMode("Automatic")
$listenerService.StartService()

$WebRoleSite = (Get-WebSite "*web*")
$WebRoleSiteName = $WebRoleSite.Name
$WebRoleAppPool = $WebRoleSite.ApplicationPool

New-ItemProperty "IIS:/Sites/$WebRoleSiteName" -name bindings -value @{protocol="net.pipe";bindingInformation="*"}
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:/Sites/$WebRoleSiteName" -Name EnabledProtocols 'http,net.pipe'

Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$WebRoleAppPool" -Name startMode -Value AlwaysRunning

write-host "End RoleStart.ps1"
```

This sets the app pool up with an AlwaysRunning property as required but I still need to supply new values for the application specific serviceAutoStartEnabled and serviceAutoStartProvider properties.

I know I can use Get-WebApplication to obtain an application and set these two properties however when I run the following powershell command I do not see an application for the root ("/")application:

```
(Get-WebApplication "*") | format-list *
```

So how can I set these two properties for the root application using the webadministration cmdlets?

Answer (score 1):

You can set these with the generic `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet. For example:

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test\" -name serviceAutoStartEnabled -Value $true
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test\" -name serviceAutoStartProvider -Value ???
```

where "Test" is a web application. Sorry, I don't know what valid values for `serviceAutoStartProvider` are. Sometimes they are integers **even when `Get-ItemProperty` shows them as strings**.

You can view the values with:

```
Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Test\" -name serviceAutoStartEnabled
```

You can also view it on the objects, eg:

```
Get-WebApplication "*" | % { Write-Output "Path: $($_.Path), AutoStartEnabled: `
  $($_.Attributes["serviceAutoStartEnabled"].Value) AutoStartProvider: `
  $($_.Attributes["serviceAutoStartProvider"].Value)" }
```

However, if you try to set `Value` you will get an error because it is readonly.

Finally, you can get and set the values with `Get-WebConfigurationProperty` and `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` and some really ugly xpath. For example:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site' and @id='1']/application[@path='/Test']" -Name serviceAutoStartEnabled
Set-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site' and @id='1']/application[@path='/Test']" -Name serviceAutoStartEnabled -Value $true
```

Note that these two cmdlets are more flexible that `Get/Set-ItemProperty` as they support all parts of configuration, whereas `Get/Set-ItemProperty` only support what is exposed by the IIS: provider.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is fairly old now, but, for those like me that come across this during searches, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;

$WebSiteName = "My Web Site";
$WebAppName = "MyWebApp";
$ProviderName = "PreWarmMyWebApp";
$ProviderType = "MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly";

Add-WebConfiguration -PSPath 'IIS:\' -Filter '/system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders' -Value @{ name=$ProviderName; type=$ProviderType };
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\' -Filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='$WebSiteName']/application[@path='/$WebAppName']" -Name "serviceAutoStartEnabled" -Value "true";
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\' -Filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='$WebSiteName']/application[@path='/$WebAppName']" -Name "ServiceAutoStartProvider" -Value $ProviderName;
```

I got the Set-WebConfigurationProperty bit from Swoogan's post but, as I figured out the serviceAutoStartProviders part myself, I thought I'd post a complete solution :)